# Excel macro is printing all sheets and not just selected one

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel macro that is launched by clicking a button.
What macro should do is print out one excel worksheet and increment value in one cell after each print.
Everything works fine EXCEPT the macro ALSO PRINTS the sheet where macro is launched (eventhough that sheet is not selected in code..)

Here is my macro code:

```vb
Sub Painike_Napsauta()
Dim i As Long

If MsgBox("Tulosta?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
Cancel = True
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
Sheets("Lappu").Range("C1").Value = Sheets("Tulosta").Range("C2").Value
For i = Sheets("Tulosta").Range("C3").Value To Sheets("Tulosta").Range("C4").Value
    Sheets("Lappu").Range("C2").Value = i
    Sheets("Lappu").PrintOut
Next i

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

So all I want to print is "Lappu" sheet in every iteration, but for some reason also "Tulosta" sheet is printed and it is the first page that is printed.

Where is the problem?

Comment: As far as I know, `PrintOut` got some optional arguments where you can specify which pages do you want to print. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.printout

Comment: Yes I can select Pages inside the sheet but that's not what I was looking for. I want to select printed sheets not pages

Comment: What do you mean with *pages inside the sheet*? A workbook is composed by one or more sheets. Sheets is the same than worksheets. And they kind of work like pages of a document. Every Sheet printed will take at least 1 page to print out (it can take more). And you say you want to print only Sheet `Lappu`, so with `Printout` you should be able to print only that one.

Comment: Yeah, I mean that I understand "page" like one A4 or some other size depend on print settings and "sheet" is that one worksheet in excel file. I know that printout should only print that one sheet which is selected but for some reason my code also printed the "Tulosta" sheet.. I wasn't able to figure out why code does that but however I was able to workaround the problem by selecting "Lappu" sheet the active and the PrintOut the active sheet

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround kind of solution to my problem:

```vb
Sub Painike_Napsauta()
Dim i As Long

If MsgBox("Tulosta?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
Cancel = True
Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheets("Lappu").Range("C1").Value = Sheets("Tulosta").Range("C2").Value
Sheets("Lappu").Range("C2").Value = Sheets("Tulosta").Range("C3").Value
Sheets("Lappu").Activate
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
For i = Sheets("Lappu").Range("C2").Value To Sheets("Tulosta").Range("C4").Value - 1
    Sheets("Lappu").Range("C2").Value = i + 1
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut
Next i

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

So I first select "Lappu" sheet the active one with .Activate and then printout the active sheet with ActiveSheet.PrintOut